# What is simplest way to show a histogram from a given sample of numbers in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, histogram

I have a CSV file which contains sample of numbers. I want to make a histogram out of the sample using Qt in QtCreator or VS 2013. The histogram should also be able to employ user interface in such a way that the user can select a range from histogram shown. But first I'd like to show a histogram at the least. Is there a simple approach to visualize a histogram from a given sample of numbers?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked [`QCustomPlot`](http://qcustomplot.com)?

Comment: i agree qcustom plot is by far the best open source charts you can interact with

Comment: @AngryDuck  Thanks for your input. Somebody as asked to close the question. How is this not question related to programming? I can't understand why this question deserved to be closed.